# Microsoft project 2016/365 assignment durations not importing correctly as 100%

Tags: xml, ms-project

Hi for our product we create an XML file to import into MS Project. It works up until 2013 but 2016/365 version doesn't import the resource unit allocations correctly. I.e. it says 100% but really its 400% i.e. not 8 hours per day but instead 32 hours per day. The fix in project is just to increase the duration. But need to fix this so it imports correctly.

```
  <Assignments>
    <Assignment>
    <UID>1</UID>
    <TaskUID>2</TaskUID>
    <ResourceUID>1</ResourceUID>
    <Finish>2017-05-26T12:00:00</Finish>
    <RegularWork>PT100H0M0S</RegularWork>
    <RemainingWork>PT100H0M0S</RemainingWork>
    <Start>2017-05-22T08:00:00</Start>
    <Units>1</Units>
    <Work>PT100H0M0S</Work>
  </Assignment>
  .....
```

1. Our export does not create **TimephasedData** for the resource assignments. Is this data now required by the new version of MS Project?
2. Is there a schema for the 2016/365 Project? I can only find up to 2010.
3. Does anyone know what changed in the XML import that now causes the issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample XML file which illustrates the problem?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i93sb6blxpl37m0/AACCLScJBrbHnrCuVk-9jVQPa?dl=0

Comment: My conclusion at the moment it to add in the TimephasedData as it seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure each assignement has TimephasedData for each day of work.

> ```
> <TimephasedData>
>     <Type>1</Type>
>     <UID>3</UID>
>     <Start>2019-04-24T08:00:00</Start>
>     <Finish>2019-04-25T08:00:00</Finish>
>     <Unit>1</Unit>
>     <Value>PT10H0M0S</Value>
> </TimephasedData>
> ```

Also if the hours per day is not the default 8 hours then you need to override the standard calendar as well.

> ```
> <WeekDay>
>     <DayType>2</DayType>
>     <DayWorking>1</DayWorking>
>     <WorkingTimes>
>         <WorkingTime>
>             <FromTime>08:00:00</FromTime>
>             <ToTime>13:00:00</ToTime>
>         </WorkingTime>
>         <WorkingTime>
>             <FromTime>14:00:00</FromTime>
>             <ToTime>19:00:00</ToTime>
>         </WorkingTime>
>     </WorkingTimes>
> </WeekDay>
> ```

Comment: Don't know why it was all fine with previous versions of project.